# Identity the same component on all connected clients

Tags: networking, client-server

I have a client-server architecture and a scene containing objects X, Y, Z, etc.

Each component needs to be identifiable so that messages sent from the server can be routed to the correct component it needs to. For example, I have 2 instances of Health component. Let's call them I1 and I2. I1 takes damage and the server updates its value and sends a message to all players to update the health of component I1 to 0.

For components that already exist in the scene when it is loaded, what I've done is assigned and serialized a unique ID at design time. But how can I handle components instantiated at runtime? For example, the same component could be instantiated on different clients but in different orders causing all the IDs to be out of whack.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what a [NetworkIdentity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkIdentity.html) is for? Why not use Unity Networking which provides this out of the box?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but as I said I am not using Unity Networking.

Comment: You may have missed the "why not" part — if you have additional constraints that make Unity Networking unsuitable for your case, it would be a good idea to include them in your question, as they might impact the kinds of solutions proposed. In particular, you should probably share some details of how you're currently instantiating objects across multiple clients, since any ID solution will likely need to be incorporated into that process, and if you're not using the standard methods then we can only guess at how your code does this.

Comment: The reason is because some of the code is ran outside Unity (the server side code) and I have plans to ditch Unity in the future. Also NetworkIdentity identifies an Object, but I would like to identify a Component.